# elasticsearch ttl force delete old messages

Tags: elasticsearch, ttl, graylog2

Im set TTL as in [manual](http://dev.nuclearrooster.com/2012/05/15/enable-elasticsearch-ttl-for-graylog2-messages/), but elasticsearch documentation said that messages older then TTL time will be not affected, how can i force deletion of older messages?

Or maybe exists some method to delete messages older then 30 days?

Comment: where exactly do you read of the 30 days constraint?

Comment: "_ttl" : { "enabled" : true, "default" : "30d" }, <<

curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/graylog2/message/_mapping
...
 "_ttl": {
"default": 2592000000
},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following from our comment back-and-forth:

I can't access that doc since it's local to your computer. But from the info is seems you're referring to a **default** of 30 days, probably set by graylog2 (I'm sure it isn't set By Elasticsearch).

But to answer your question: if you've got a timestamp field on your documents do a delete-by-query on that timestamp (select all docs older than 30 days and delete). http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html.

To be save, be sure to do a fetch first on the same query instead of a delete to see if you've actually formulated the query correctly.

If you don't have a timestamp on your documents, I'm really not sure how to do this. Still I like to see evidence/docs that Elasticsearch doesn't delete these according to the TTL.